# How to sample only odd numbers in the domain of a table for list plot

Tags: list-manipulation, plotting

The following code samples $k$ points around a circle at integer values starting from $0$:

```
ListPlot[Table[{2 Sin[(2*y/x)*π*n] , 2 Cos[(2*y/x)*π*n}], {n, 0, k}]
```

I wish instead to sample every other point. So instead of running $n$ from $0$ to $k$, I want the function plotted at $n=0,2,4,...2m$ or $n=1,3,5,...2r+1$ (I am assuming that the method is the same for both of these cases). How can I implement this?

Comment: Change the iterator to  `{n, 0, k, 2}`

Comment: You also have some syntax errors in your code (some of the brackets are mixed up). The correct syntax that samples only odd numbers is `ListPlot[Table[{2 Sin[(2 y \[Pi] n)/x], 2 Cos[(2 y \[Pi] n)/x]}, {n, 
   1, k, 2}]]`.

Comment: @belisarius: Almost, but that samples even numbers, I think the OP wants odd numbers.

Comment: I am assuming I can do {n,1,k,2} for odd?

Comment: In any case, this is easily found in the Documentation Center page for `Table`, so I'll vote to close.

Comment: @illysial: Yes, see the code in my comments above.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Yup. _"almost, but not quite, entirely unlike tea"_

Comment: @belisarius: http://www.silvergames.com/tea-party-simulator-2014

Comment: @illysial: Just to sum up the comments, you use `{n, 0, k, 2}` to sample 0 through k in chunks of 2 (ie, even numbers), or you can use `{n, 1, k, 2}` to sample 1 through k in chunks of 2 (ie, odd numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will rework your code to show where the points lie on the plot.

```
With[{x = 11, y = 3, k = 7},
  ListPlot[
    Table[{{2 Sin[(2*y/x)*π*n], 2 Cos[(2*y/x)*π*n]}}, {n, 0, k}],
    PlotStyle -> {{Red, FontSize -> 20}},
    PlotMarkers -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}]]
```

[image: all-pts]

Now I will pick only the odd numbered points

```
With[{x = 11, y = 3, k = 7},
  ListPlot[
    Table[{{2 Sin[(2*y/x)*π*n], 2 Cos[(2*y/x)*π*n]}}, {n, 1, k, 2}],
    PlotStyle -> {{Red, FontSize -> 20}},
    PlotMarkers -> {1, 3, 5, 7}]]
```

[image: odd-pts]

and here I pick the even numbered points

```
With[{x = 11, y = 3, k = 7},
   ListPlot[
     Table[{{2 Sin[(2*y/x)*π*n], 2 Cos[(2*y/x)*π*n]}}, {n, 0, k, 2}],
     PlotStyle -> {{Red, FontSize -> 20}},
     PlotMarkers -> {0, 2, 4, 6}]]]
```

[image: even-pts]